# Select records that are x days older than the current date

Tags: php, mysql, date, compare

I am trying to Select records that are older than X days from a MySQL table 'my_table' and column 'Last_updated_time' in a PHP file. I tried various combinations. My column 'Last_updated time' is in Varchar and NOT Date type.

My select statement looked something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE  str_to_date(Last_updated_time, '%d/%m/%Y') < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL  X DAY) AND Place='So_and_So'  ";
```

I even tried this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (Last_updated_time < NOW() - INTERVAL X DAY) AND Place=' So_and_So' ";
```

I use the result to send as JSON to be parsed in my Android file.

Please help me. I searched all SO a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Your question might also provide an answer to the following: What is 'X' and/or where does it come from?  What happens with the shown queries?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Last_updated_time, '%m/%d/%Y') < CURDATE() - INTERVAL X DAYS
AND Place='So_and_So'
```

Are you sure the format of the Last_updated_time is dd/mm/yyyy? If not, you should alter the '%m/%d/%Y' part.

Sorry for all the edits, I keep messing up :P

One last edit:

You should really think about changing the Last_updated_time field to a date type. You could make a temporary column and update the entire table with something like this.

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET `temp_updated_time` = STR_TO_DATE(Last_updated_time, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

After that you can delete the old column and rename the new column to the old column name.  This should speed up searching enormously, because the str_to_date is quite slow. Offcourse you should also change your code if needed. Always go for the faster / permanent solution if you can!

Comment: Recommendation to use a date type is spot on.

Comment: FYI it's "INTERVAL X DAY" not "INTERVAL X DAYS"